# How to compute the integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin^2(x-t)}{a+\cos(x-t)} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to compute the integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin^2(x-t)}{a+\cos(x-t)} \, dx$ ?

Is it possible to integrate?

I tried by elementary methods without much luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

I can think of two suggestions:

1) For $|a|>1$ expand the denominator into series:

$$\frac{1}{a+\cos(x-t)}=\frac{1}{a} \left(1-\frac{\cos(x-t)}{a}+\frac{\cos^2(x-t)}{a^2} -\frac{\cos^3(x-t)}{a^3}+.\dots \right) $$

$$\frac{1}{a} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2}(1-\cos^2(x-t)) \left(1-\frac{\cos(x-t)}{a}+\frac{\cos^2(x-t)}{a^2} -\frac{\cos^3(x-t)}{a^3}+.\dots \right)dx$$

It's not the best way, since I don't know if the integral has closed form for a general term.

For a finite amount of terms you can use trig identities, like:

$$\cos^2 (x-t)=\frac{1}{2} (1+\cos (2x-2t))$$

---

2) Another, more useful way is to expand the trigonometric part of the integral into Fourier series.

> Again, it's possible only for $|a|>1$.

First, it's better to change the variable $x-t=y$:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin^2(x-t)}{a+\cos(x-t)} \, dx=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-(y+t)^2}\sin^2(y)}{a+\cos(y)} \, dy$$

Since the trigonometric part is even and periodic with period $2 \pi$, we can expand it into cosine Fourier series:

$$\frac{\sin^2 (y)}{a+\cos(y)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \cos{n y}$$

$$A_0=\frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_0 \frac{\sin^2 (y)}{a+\cos(y)} dy=a-\sqrt{a^2-1}$$

> $$A_n=\frac{2}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_0 \frac{\sin^2 (y)}{a+\cos(y)} \cos(ny) dy$$

The last integral in general is expressed in terms of regularized hypergeometric functions, however for natural $n$ it is expressed in radicals (you can check with Mathematica). For example:

> $$A_1=1-2a(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})$$
>
> $$A_2=2 \sqrt{a^2-1}~~ (1-2a(a-\sqrt{a^2-1}))$$
>
> $$A_3=2  \sqrt{a^2-1} ~~ ((4a^2-1)(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})-2a)$$
>
> $$\dots$$

You can express your integral as a series:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin^2(x-t)}{a+\cos(x-t)} \, dy=(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})\sqrt{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos(n (x-t)) dx$$

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos(n (x-t)) dx=\sqrt{\pi}~ e^{-n^2/4} \cos (nt)$$

> $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin^2(x-t)}{a+\cos(x-t)} \, dy=\sqrt{\pi} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n e^{-n^2/4} \cos (nt) \right)$$

---

For the case $a=1$ we can easily see that:

$$A_1=-1$$

$$A_n=0,~~~~n>1$$

So the solution contains only two terms:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-(y+t)^2}\sin^2(y)}{1+\cos(y)} \, dy=\sqrt{\pi} \left(1-\frac{\cos (t)}{\sqrt[4]{e}} \right)$$

**Update**

I asked a question here to find $A_n$ in closed form and [Start wearing purple](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73025/start-wearing-purple) was kind enough to [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696200/269624):

> $$A_{n\ge2}=2(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{a^2-1}\left(a-\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)^{n}$$

So I would consider your question answered as best as it could.

Comment: using your advice I can reduce the integral to this:

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-(x^2)/2} sin^2(x-t) dx}{a+cos(x-t)} =  \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{a} - \frac{2}{a^2} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}}cos(t)+ \sum_ {n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (\frac{2^n}{a^{n+1}}- \frac{2^{n-2}}{a^{n-1}})(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}cos^{n}(x-t)dx )  $

any idea to solve this integral analytically $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}cos^{n}(x-t)dx $

Comment: Where did $2$ come from? It was just $e^{-x^2}$ in your question. As for the general integral, I'll get back to you when I think of something. You can easily see that without $2$ and for $a=1$ you get a simple two term solution - the same as [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B-x%5E2%7D%5Csin%5E2(x-t)%7D%7B1%2B%5Ccos(x-t)%7D+%5C,+dx)

Comment: Wow. thank you very much!
This really solves my question, and the solution is simple.

Comment: You are welcome. I checked numerically, even taking $4$ terms in the series for $a=3$ we get a very good fit with the numerical value of the integral. You can accept answers at Math.SE by clicking the checkbox on the left under the arrows